# Looking for a German quote about politics and opinions

Tags: phrase-request, reference-request

I am searching for a German quote I read some time time ago.

Here is what I remember:

- It is about politics
- The general meaning was something like this: Don't adopt the opinion/beliefs of the public. Instead make your opinion/beliefs popular.
- Length was about 2-3 sentences.
- I read the quote in German and I am pretty sure the author was German as well

Trying to find the quote using google the following quote popped up a lot, but this is not the quote I am looking for.

> Immer wenn man die Meinung der Mehrheit teilt, ist es Zeit, sich zu
>   besinnen.

by Mark Twain

Comment: **To close voters:** [we said that it is OK to ask in Meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/is-searching-for-a-german-quote-on-topic) - if you disagree please join the discussion there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Es kann nicht die Aufgabe eines Politikers sein, die öffentliche Meinung abzuklopfen und dann das Populäre zu tun. Aufgabe des Politikers ist es, das Richtige zu tun und es populär zu machen.

Is a saying by [Walter Scheel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Scheel), former foreign minister, acting chancellor (after Willy Brandt's resignment) and the famous singing Bundespräsident (I'd bet the only President who ever had a top-ten single (5) in the German charts).

Answer (score -2):

How about

> Die kluge Forelle schwimmt gegen den Strom.

Comment: To whom is this attributed?